# Stanford POS tag out of memory

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I trying to load the my own trained tagger call mytagger.tagger(size: 265KB)  and it throw error below

```
Loading default properties from tagger taggers/mytagger.tagger
Reading POS tagger model from taggers/mytagger.tagger ... Whoops! Incomplete read. Rewrite the   code!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Below is coding:

```
MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger("taggers/mytagger.tagger");
```

My Java is 64bit and using NetBeans 7.3.1. I try increase the memory size to -Xms4096M but it still the throw the same error message.

Anyone have solution for this issue. Thank you....

Keith

Comment: What version of the tagger is this?  Has the code been altered?  That is, the message "Whoops! Incomplete read. Rewrite the   code!" definitely isn't in the code of the current version of the tagger, and I don't remember it being in any version....  Try training and running again on the current distribution, unaltered?

Comment: `-Xms4096M` specifies the starting memory of the Java process. Try explicitly specifying the maximum memory with `-Xmx4096M`.